# How to Unset Magento Error Message Session?

Tags: magento

I need to unset the error message session in magento for below code.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($message);
```

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be able to use the following code, though it will return all messages (it will not echo them), it will clear them:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMessages(true); // The true is for clearing them after loading them
```

I hope this answers your question. ^_^